# Plotting matplotlib bar using for loop from MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to load data from my MySQL database with a query that returns the `SUM()` of COVID-19 deaths per month using `for` loop.

```py
january = february = march = april = may = june = july = august = september = october = november = december = 0

meses = [january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december]

for i, m in enumerate(meses):
    c.execute(f'SELECT SUM(deaths) FROM covid WHERE month = {i+1} AND countriesAndTerritories = "United_States_of_America";')
    m = c.fetchall()
    print(f'i = {i+1} / c = {m}')

x = np.array(['JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTUBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER'])
y = np.array([january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december])

plt.title("Deaths per Month - 2020")
plt.bar(x,y, color = "indigo")
plt.show()
```

Inside the `for` loop, I make a `print` to check the information extracted from the database and it returns it like this:

```py
i = 1 / c = [(0.0,)]
i = 2 / c = [(0.0,)]
i = 3 / c = [(3170.0,)]
i = 4 / c = [(57796.0,)]
i = 5 / c = [(42815.0,)]
i = 6 / c = [(22359.0,)]
i = 7 / c = [(25930.0,)]
i = 8 / c = [(30999.0,)]
i = 9 / c = [(22929.0,)]
i = 10 / c = [(23710.0,)]
i = 11 / c = [(37165.0,)]
i = 12 / c = [(32304.0,)]
```

The `print` confirms that the data was captured by the database. What would be the reason for the information in the bar graph to be zeroed as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach could be simplified significantly ***without looping*** if you `GROUP BY` in `SQL` and use `read_sql` with no need to pass parameters.

Then, just call `plt.bar()` and pass the columns. From there, you can use `plt.xticks` to change the format of the months from `0,1,2,etc.` to the `month_format` list of desired  month names.

NOTE: I'm not a `mysql` user but I think the `month` column name could be confused with the `SQL` function `month`, so I've included as `month` as I have read this is the `SQL Server` equivalent to `[month]`.

```
# c =  your connection
sql='''
SELECT `month`, SUM(deaths) as deaths FROM covid WHERE countriesAndTerritories = "United_States_of_America" GROUP BY `month` ORDER BY `month`;
'''

df = pd.read_sql(sql, c)

month_format = np.array(['JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTUBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER'])
plt.bar(df['month'],df['deaths'], color="indigo")
plt.title("Deaths per Month - 2020")
plt.xticks(x_data, month_format)
plt.show()
```